# How to stop looping in activites and at the same handle the default on screen navigation back?

Tags: java, android

```
    ImageView Back = findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Wallet.this, Nav.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button cash = findViewById(R.id.button11);

    cash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Wallet.this, Cash.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    TextView Card = findViewById(R.id.textView26);
    Card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Wallet.this, Card.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    Button AddCard = findViewById(R.id.button12);

    AddCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Wallet.this, AddedCard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    TextView promo = findViewById(R.id.textView28);

    promo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Wallet.this, promocode.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    Button Voucher = findViewById(R.id.button13);

    Voucher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Wallet.this, Vouchers.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

If i remove finish(); this create loops when I press default navigation back button.
like if I visited promocode class,then voucher class.from vouchar class I want to go back in Main Class by pressing default navigation back button.it will reverse like vouchar to promode then main class.
But I want by default back button will bring me vouchar class to directly main class.

But after adding finish(); whenever i press navigation back button the app quits.

I want a solution that...default navigation back button will act like my every customized back button for every each individuals frames !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to provide proper navigation.
Here's the [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) to understand the tasks and back stack.

The other way to provide back navigation to the custom activity is to override onBackPressed() method of your activity like :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    startActivity(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```